# Modify a value on a PHP/mysql table and update the table on the server

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table, updates

I have a table with football matches and predictions.

```
| ID | home_team | home_result | away_team | away_result | date&time | location
```

I can show the table on php but how can i use this table to update "home result" and "away result" on the server? and how can i disable this fields after the match started?

This code works fine but I can't modify local and away results from this. I would like to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvFS5.jpg):

[image]

**Update Code working

```
 <html> 
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
 </form> 
 <form action="pruebalista.php" method="post" name="groups" >  
 <select name="value">  
    <option value="All">All</option> 
    <option value="A">A</option>  
    <option value="B">B</option>  
    <option value="C">C</option>  
     <option value="D">D</option>  
    <option value="E">E</option>  
    <option value="F">F</option>  
     <option value="G">G</option>  
    <option value="H">H</option>  
       </select>  
 <br />  
 <input type='submit' value = 'Filter'>  
 </form> 



<?php  
//connect to database, checking, etc  
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","password","world_cup");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// process form when posted 
if(isset($_POST['value'])) { 
if($_POST['value'] == 'All') { 

   $query = "SELECT * FROM matches";   
}   
else {   

    $value=$_POST['value'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE Group='$value'";   
    }
 } else {   
    // query to get all records   
     $query = "SELECT * FROM partidos ORDER BY Group";   
 }


$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
$count=mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
?>

<form action="update.PHP" method="post" name="update" >   

<?php

echo "<table border='3'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Grupo</th>
<th>Local</th>
<th>Resultado_local</th>
<th>Visitante</th>
<th>Resultado_visitante</th>
<th>Hora</th>
<th>Sede</th>
</tr>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){      
         ?>
        <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
        <?php            
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['Group'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['home'] . "</td>";
        if ($row['Disabled'] === '1'){
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto> <input type='text' name='home_res[]' disabled value='". $row['Resultado_local'] . "'/></td>";
       echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto> <input type='text'  name='away_res[]' disabled value='". $row['Resultado_visitante'] . "'/></td>";</td>";

        }
        else{
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto> <input type='text' name='home_res[]' value='". $row['Resultado_local'] . "'/></td>";
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto> <input type='text'  name='away_res[]' value='". $row['Resultado_visitante'] . "'/></td>";</td>";

        }

        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['Visitante'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
} 
mysqli_close($con);  

echo "</table>";
?> 
<input type='submit' value ='update'>  
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Finally I decided to use update.php. This is the code:

```
 <?php

 include 'pruebalista.php';

 // Connect to server and select database. 

//connect to database, checking, etc  
$con=mysqli_connect("192.168.36.251","kpsadmin","Bicentenario","mundial");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

// find out how many records there are to update 
//$size = count($_POST['away_res']); 
 $size = count($_POST['home_res']); 

// start a loop in order to update each record 
$i = 0; 
while ($i < $size) { 
// define each variable 
$home = $_POST['home_res'][$i]; 
$away= $_POST['away_res'][$i]; 
$id = $_POST['id'][$i]; 


 // do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback 
 $query = "UPDATE $tabla SET `Home_result`='$home', `Away_result`='$away' WHERE   `ID`='$id'"; 
 mysqli_query($con , $query) or die ("Error in query: $query"); 

 ++$i; 

 } 
 header("location: pruebalista.php");
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)

Comment: Please do a little research, this is the basis of php... I give you the answer if you don't have any idea soon.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain well my english is not very good, i want to update the table directly changing data on the table that appears on the main page.

Comment: Take some time for learn how to programming, because you seem to be a little lost. If your application is connected to the dataBase, you just have to do a SQL request UPDATE. For that, PHP have function for execute SQL. For exemple: $sql = 'Update matable set champ1 = champ1 + 1 where id = 33';
mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

Take some time for learn how to programming, because you seem to be a little lost. If your application is connected to the DataBase, you just have to do a SQL request UPDATE.

For that, PHP have function for execute SQL.

For exemple:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$passwd = "";
$database = "test";

// server connection
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user,$passwd);
if (!$link) {
  die('Error');
}

// database connection
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Error');
}

$sql = 'Update matable set champ1 = champ1 + 1 where id = 33';
mysql_query($sql);
```

If you have more precise question, maybe I can help you.

EDIT:
OK So it's a little more complicated.
Begin to add other form before your while. add :

```
echo "<td valign=middle align=center width=auto>
<input type='text' name='home_res' value='". $row['home_result'] . "'/></td>";
```

Same think for away result.
Add an input for submit your form (like in our screenshoot)
Now you can retrive data from this form using $_POST['home_res'] for exemple.
Make an UPDATE sql request and execute with the new data.

After you can disable an text input by HTML like that :

```
<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>
```

And make a little Javascript for remove disabled from your input when time is passed.

It's will work find!

Comment: Thank you ottoPsy, i updated my question i hope you can understand my question. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I'm at work now, I give you the answer in late afternoon.

Comment: Thank you, it works the part of the input text but i cannot update the table. i updated my code if you could check...

Comment: are you sure you have update all you're code? where is your text input?

Comment: sorry i didn't change that part of the code, updated now

Comment: i don't understand why you want to do a loop for? and $count variable is not initialized. Are you sure  to understand what you do in this section?

Comment: i did a loop to update each row in the table because the user can modify more than one row. Added the $count variable.

Comment: try to understand what are you doing. Have you heard about array? You write: $home_result = $_POST['home_res']; and after you try to iterate on a simple variable text. echo $home_result; and you will understand what I want to tell.

Comment: i am very lost..., i did a small test and i realised that $_POST['home_res'] and $_POST['away_res'] values are the values of the last row. How can i retrieve all data?

Comment: Explain me what do you want to do clearly. If I understand you want to update ALL your match table's rows who correspond to the group selected with only one form? It's seems to be a no sense.  Take five minutes and think about what you want to do. What is the $count value?

Comment: HI Julien, finally i got the code working for update  mysql table from form  but still i dont know how to use a good way to disable the input after a match started. i added a new column to the mysql table called disable with 2 possible values (0,1), if the value is 1 i add to the input line the disable option, any ideas ? i dont know javascript... Thanks